# Upper bound to sum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X,Y$ be rea random variables with cdf $F_X, F_Y$, respectively. I have to find an upper bound to
$$\mathbb P(X+Y>t)\qquad t\in \mathbb R$$
without supposing the independence of $X,Y$, otherwise the solution is simply found by convolution.

My Idea is to define
$$Z = t-X$$
so that the problem should reduce to the comparison between
$$F_Z(x) = F_{t-X}(x)= 1-F_X(t-x);\qquad F_Y(x)$$
but then I cannot proceed in a riguros way.

Comment: Do you have any additional inormation on $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: If $X+Y>t$ then either $X>t/2$ or $Y>t/2$.